# Relationship between negation in discrete mathematics and duality in Boolean algebra.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, boolean-algebra

I have been studying duality and I am confused at the point that how are the two linked.

For example in discrete mathematics we see
$$
{\sim}(A \land B) = {\sim}A \lor {\sim}B.
$$
But in Boolean algebra using the rules of Duality we see that
$$
A\ \text{and } B = A\ \text{or } B.
$$
My question is that are the concepts linked together and if so don't they prove each other to be wrong?

Comment: I think you have made a mistake in your statement about Boolean algebras: can you say a bit more about how you arrived at that statement. Also, it is recommended to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format mathematical formulas on MSE.

Comment: first of all I'm sorry for the wrong format, I am new to this. secondly I was studying the concept of duality and what I understood was that A + B can be changed to A . B and A . B to A + B.

Comment: $A + B$ and $A . B$ are not equivalent in Boolean algebra. If you change the connective from $+$ to $.$, you have to introduce negations, just as you did you did when you wrote it using $\land$ and $\lor$.

Comment: Isn't this what the concept of duality tells us.  What I studied was that we have to replace all + with . and all 1s with 0s and as there is no 1 or 0 here, wouldn't it become like this.

Comment: The rule you are thinking of only applies when your formula doesn't contain any variables: when you are replacing $1$s with $0$s and vice versa what you are doing is negating the truth values. When you have propositional variables $A$ and $B$ representing truth values, you have to negate those variables.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification. I thought it applied to variables as well. With 1s and 0s I understand that it would work. Thank you.

Comment: @AbdullahBilal Incidentally, the "swap $0$ and $1$" clause is a *particular case of* "negate the inner terms:" we have $\sim 0=1$ and $\sim 1=0$. There really is no difference between the two settings. (Incidentally, we also see a parallel duality with respect to $\cap$ and $\cup$; this reflects the tight connection between abstract Boolean algebras and powerset algebras. And there's a similar duality when we look at quantifiers: "$\forall x[P(x)]$" is the same as "$\sim \exists x[\sim P(x)]$" and so forth.)

Answer (score 1):

I hope this answer helps someone else who also like me is confused between the concepts of negation and Duality.

In the negation part, we see that the right hand side of the equation is equal to the left hand side of the same equation that is

∼(A ∧ B) = ∼A ∨ ∼B

but on the other hand, in duality if we take the example

A or 1 = 1

through duality we see that

A and 0 = 0

This does not mean that

A and 0

and

A or 1

are equivalent. It just means that they are both true and logically correct, ie duality helps us create new laws that are logically correct.